# Detrending a time-series by means of Discrete Wavelet Transform

Tags: time-series, wavelet-analysis

I plot a time-series for observation as you can see in the plot:

[image]

I tried to detrend the time series by 3 different approaches which are: 1) differences, 2) detrended fluctuation analysis, and 3) discrete wavelet transform, thus I obtain the attached plot:

[image]

In order to apply discrete wavelet transform approach I followed the directions provided in Help page of Mathematica to make detrending i.e I used the below code:

```
dwdfa = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data, SymletWavelet[3], 2, 
  Padding -> "Extrapolated"]
```

and then I calibrated the `SymletWavelet` and refinement parameters to make the detrended series correlated with the other approaches I mean `SymletWavelet[3`],and ***2***, .

My question here is would please explain me how to figure out those parameters correctly without making such calibration. I read some theoretical explanations but still I am  fresh in wavelet analysis and most of time I get confused about this.

Comment: Can you make your data available ? Also, does the de-trending have to be done through Wavelet Analysis or any other approach would be acceptable?

Comment: Look at question [`(69953)`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69953/wavelet-transform-of-data-with-sliders/69961#69961) for a couple of solutions

Comment: @AntonAntonov, I am trying to get more about different approaches of detrending, hence I am trying to understand wavelet more.

Comment: @Sektor, Thank you for your comment however, still I did not understand what is the best coefficient  that I can figure out without using the other methods.
In other words, Iam interested in understanding the nature of fluctuation in my time series in by extracting only the fluctuation component. 
The provided question gives more smooth data than extracting the fluctuation component

Comment: `GraphicsGrid[
 Map[ListLinePlot[#, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"] &, 
  Map[Last, Map[dwd[{___, #}] &, {0, 1}], {2}], {2}]]` where `dwd` is the `DiscreteWaveletTransform` of your data. This will give you an insight into your data set. Also -- search the documentation for `DiscreteWaveletTransform` and read under *Details and Options*.  [`View sample plot`](http://i.imgur.com/LWPhurF.png)

Comment: @M.Basel Any progress ?

Comment: @Sektor, thanx for asking to be honest with you I am focusing on some points of DFA, once I finish I will tell you about my progress for sure just wait. Best